# Referencing PCLCrypto in a NetStandard1.3 project

Tags: portable-class-library, .net-standard, project.json

I'm trying to add a reference to the package PCLCrypto (2.0.147) in a project using NetStandard 1.3

After I add the import "portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81" in the project.json, it builds, but keep showing the errors.

---

project.json:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1",
    "PCLCrypto": "2.0.147",
    "System.ComponentModel.Primitives": "4.1.0",
    "WraUtil.Helpers": "1.8.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.3": {
      "imports": "portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81"
    }
  }
}
```

---

errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Package PInvoke.NCrypt 0.3.2 is not compatible with netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3). Package PInvoke.NCrypt 0.3.2 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - portable-net40+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile92)
  - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
Error       Package Validation 2.2.8 is not compatible with netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3). Package Validation 2.2.8 supports:
  - dotnet (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0)
  - portable-dnxcore50+monoandroid10+monotouch10+net45+win+wp8+wpa81+xamarinios10 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net45+dnxcore50+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10)
  - portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile328)
Error       Package PCLCrypto 2.0.147 is not compatible with netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3). Package PCLCrypto 2.0.147 supports:
  - monoandroid23 (MonoAndroid,Version=v2.3)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - portable-win81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile32)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.3.
Error       Package PCLCrypto 2.0.147 is not compatible with netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3). Package PCLCrypto 2.0.147 supports:
  - monoandroid23 (MonoAndroid,Version=v2.3)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - portable-win81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile32)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
Error       One or more packages are incompatible with .NETStandard,Version=v1.3.
Error       Package Validation 2.2.8 is not compatible with netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3). Package Validation 2.2.8 supports:
  - dotnet (.NETPlatform,Version=v5.0)
  - portable-dnxcore50+monoandroid10+monotouch10+net45+win+wp8+wpa81+xamarinios10 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=net45+dnxcore50+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10)
  - portable-net40+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile328)
Error       Package PInvoke.NCrypt 0.3.2 is not compatible with netstandard1.3 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.3). Package PInvoke.NCrypt 0.3.2 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - portable-net40+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile92)
  - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
```

---

Do I need to configure anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `imports` field in your `project.json` file, you should put a target framework which is compatible with PCLCrypto 2.0.147, and those errors are basically telling you which options you have.

For example, one of those supported target frameworks is `portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81` which is compatible with `netstandard1.0`, which means that it can be also referenced by a `netstandard1.3` project (you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library#pcl-compatibility) more info about compatibility between the old PCL profiles and new .NET Standard versions).

So, update your `imports` field to: `"imports": "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"`.

Small bonus - in case you decide to move from `project.json` to new MSBuild (csproj) style projects, you can achieve the same with:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.3</TargetFramework>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I put the import in every netstandard1.3 project of my solution. It compiles normally and the messages were gone.